# Почему некоторые слова API Яндекс.Переводчика не переводит, а оставляет как есть, но через сайт переводит отлично?

Tags: яндекс-переводчик

Заметил такую особенность, что некоторые слова API Яндекс.Переводчика не переводит, а оставляет как есть, НО через веб-версию сайта translate.yandex.ru переводит отлично!

Пример, слово "брюнеточка":

[image: Перевод через api]

[image: Перевод через сайт]

И таких примеров я встречал довольно много. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Вопрос в тех.поддержку яндекса уже написал, жду ответа.

Comment: Можете Google Translate использовать, работает классно. И есть хороший пакет для PHP. На сколько я знаю, Яндекс тоже использует переводчик гугла, часть, не на всех языках, но информация не точная

Comment: google translate насколько знаю только платный, а у яндекса есть бесплатный лимит для перевода :)

Comment: Нет, google translate бесплатный и безлимитный

Comment: Если только где-то в параллельной вселенной. Загляните сюда https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php Можно бесплатно переводить без проблем - проверил.

Comment: Valeriu Vodnicear, "google translate бесплатный и безлимитный" Неправда. Недокументированное web-api (то которое через формочку работает) естественно бесплатное. На то оно и недокументированное. А документированное REST API для разработчиков стало платным даже раньше чем у яндекса. То есть давно. Так что проверяйте факты. PHP -либа, естественно юзает, недокументированное web API гугла. И там есть лимиты, которые установил гугл: 5 тыс. символов за один запрос. Так что опять вы не проверили факт.

Answer (score 0):

Ответила поддержка яндекса:

"На translate.yandex.ru http://translate.yandex.ru/  работает новый перевод на основе нейросетей (https://yandex.ru/blog/company/kak-pobedit-mornikov-yandeks-zapustil-gibridnuyu-sistemu-perevoda). Через API он пока не доступен. Со временем мы постараемся добавить его также и для API, но пока каких-то сроков решения назвать не можем. "

Comment: Как теперь получать free api key? Может есть вариант через php как в гугл?

Comment: "Как теперь получать free api key?" Никак. Их больше не существует в природе.

Comment: "Может есть вариант через php как в гугл? " Есть. У меня сервис может переводить до 1 млрд. символов в день. Через yandex.translate.